# Objects using jQuery to maintain a playlist of shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented, form, dom

This is my first attempt at using OOP JavaScript in my work. I know the concepts but implementation is more complicated than I thought. Now the code is a mixture of several things (JavaScript/jQuery).

The code works well however I am not sure if it is proper OOP (don't like the way it looks - tons of `this`).

I know there are more efficient ways to write it, but I am not sure where to start and would like to know if I'm going in the right direction, or if I should start from scratch.

```
function Show(parent, cln_elm) {
    this.d_button = "";
    this.e_button = "";
    this.row = "";
    this.cln_elm = cln_elm;
    this.cln = "";
    this.active = false;
    this.indexid = "";
    this.select = 0;
    this.p = parent;

    this.obj = {
        id: "",
        type: "",
        name: "",
        color: "",
        template: "",
        title: "",
        subtitle_1: "",
        subtitle_2: "",
        subtitle_3: "",
        assets: "",
        logo: "",
        i_user: "",
        video_id: "",
    };
}
Show.prototype = {
    constructor: Show,
    create: function(elm, id) {
        this.indexid = id;
        this.obj["id"] = id;
        var fields = elm.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].name == undefined || fields[i].value == undefined) {
                console.log("undefined");
            }
            if (fields[i].type == "radio") {
                if (fields[i].checked == true) {
                    this.obj[fields[i].name] = fields[i].value;
                }
            } else {
                this.obj[fields[i].name] = fields[i].value;
            }
        };
        this.display(elm.parentElement);
        this.store();
    },
    edit: function() {
        this.p.id_reg = this.obj["id"];
        this.active = true;
        this.p.active = this.active;
        var fields = $($(this.row).parents()[3]).children().eq(1);
        var all = fields[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i in all) {
            if (this.obj[all[i].name]) {
                all[i].value = this.obj[all[i].name]
            }
        }
        $($(this.row).parents()[3]).children().eq(0).hide();
        $($(this.row).parents()[3]).children().eq(1).show();
    },
    deletes: function(elm) {
        $(this.cln).remove();
        $(this.row).remove();
        var index = this.p.ids.indexOf(this.obj["id"]);
        this.p.shows.splice(index, 1);
        this.p.ids.splice(index, 1);
    },
    store: function() {
        var info = $.map(this.obj, function(value, index) {
            return [value].join("&");
        });
    },
    activate: function() {},
    display: function(elm) {
        var tab = $(elm).parent().find($('TABLE'));
        var full = document.getElementById(this.cln_elm);
        this.row = $("<tr>")
            .append($("<td>").text(this.obj["name"]))
            .append($("<td>").text(this.obj["type"]))
            .append($("<td>").text("details of show"))
            .append($("<td>").append($("<button/>").addClass("edit_show").text("Edit")))
            .append($("<td>").append($("<button/>").addClass("delete_show").text("Delete")))
            .append($("<td>").append($("<input type='checkbox'/>").addClass("activate_show")))

        $(tab).append(this.row);
        $(full).append(this.cln);

        this.cln = $(this.row).clone(true, true);
        var all = [this.row, this.cln];
        for (i in all) {
            $(all[i]).find($(".delete_show"))[0].addEventListener("click", this.deletes.bind(this), false);
            $(all[i]).find($(".edit_show"))[0].addEventListener("click", this.edit.bind(this), false);
            $(all[i]).find($(".activate_show"))[0].addEventListener("change", this.activate.bind(this), false);
        }
    },
}

function List(elmId) {
    this.shows = [];
    this.ids = [];
    this.id_Reg;
    this.active = "false";
    this.elmId = elmId;
}
List.prototype = {
    constructor: List,
    loadShow: function() {},
    createShow: function(e) {
        this.showid = "";
        this.newid = "";
        this.len = "";
        if (this.shows < 0) {
            this.len = -1;
        } else {
            this.len = this.shows.length - 1
        }
        if (this.active == true) {
            this.showid = this.ids.indexOf(this.id_reg);
            this.active = false;
            console.log(this.shows[this.showid]);
        } else {
            if (this.shows.length > 0) {
                this.newid = this.shows[this.len].obj.id + 1;
            } else {
                this.newid = 0;
            }
            this.show = new Show(this, this.elmId);
            this.show.create(e.target, this.newid);
            this.shows.push(this.show);
            this.ids.push(this.newid);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.target).parent().parent().children().eq(0).show();
        $(e.target).parent().parent().children().eq(1).hide();
    }
}


var list = new List('finalplaylist');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var c_show = $('.store_show');

    for (var i = 0; i < c_show.length; i++) {
        var elm = c_show[i];
        elm.addEventListener('click', list.createShow.bind(list), false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Please note, from ECMAScript 2015 (ECMA-262, 6th Edition or ES6), some of the following advice will change. In particular, ES6 offers [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). At the time of writing, ES6 is only sporadically supported in browsers*

On a general point, unlike PHP/Java, JavaScript has classless constructors. What looks like a "class" is actually a constructor, therefore you can do more in `function Foo(){...}` than just declare its members. You can execute any statement you like including calls to methods established on the `prototype`.

Regarding `this` :

- any `this.xxx` member that exists only as a means-to-an-end within the same method should be a var.
- you can use the semantic convenience of `var list = this;` and `var show = this;` at the top of methods to avoid the overuse of `this` elsewhere in the method. But such an assignment is often more than a convenience when there are inner functions, which have their own `this`.

Something you might strive for is a better separation of concerns :

- allow `Show` methods to do only Show stuff, with no awareness of List.
- allow `List` methods to do only List stuff, including the creation of new Shows and interacting with them via Show methods, but with no awareness of List's internal workings.
- arrange for only the initializer to know about the static DOM containers (all that `.parent().parent()` stuff).

The following code is designed to demonstrate the above principles. Its probably not 100% correct; I had to make a number of educated guesses particularly regarding the static DOM hierarchy. If you want to try it, be prepared to do some debugging.

```
function Show(id, $inputFields) {
    this.active = false;
    this.obj = {
        id: id,
        type: '',
        name: '',
        color: '',
        template: '',
        title: '',
        subtitle_1: '',
        subtitle_2: '',
        subtitle_3: '',
        assets: '',
        logo: '',
        i_user: '',
        video_id: ''
    };
    this.create($inputFields);
}
Show.prototype = {
    'create': function($inputFields) {
        var show = this;
        $inputFields.each(function(i, field) {
            if (field.name == undefined || field.value == undefined) {
                console.log('undefined');
            }
            if (field.type == 'radio') {
                if (field.checked) {
                    show.obj[field.name] = field.value;
                }
            } else {
                show.obj[field.name] = field.value;
            }
        });
        this.store();
    },
    'store': function() {
        var show = this;
        var info = $.map(show.obj, function(value, index) {
            return value;
        }).join('&');
        // ... do something with info
    },
    'edit': function($inputFields) {
        var show = this;
        $inputFields.each(function(i, input) {
            if (show.obj[input.name]) {
                input.value = show.obj[input.name];
            }
        });
    },
    'makeRow': function() {
        var show = this;
        // Simply return the jQuery-wrapped row; it will be appended by the caller.
        return $('<tr/>')
            .append($('<td/>').text(show.obj['name']))
            .append($('<td/>').text(show.obj['type']))
            .append($('<td/>').text('details of show'))
            .append($('<td/>').append($('<button/>').addClass('edit_show').text('Edit')))
            .append($('<td/>').append($('<button/>').addClass('delete_show').text('Delete')))
            .append($('<td/>').append($('<input type="checkbox"/>').addClass('activate_show')));
    }
}

function List(elmId) {
    this.shows = [];
    this.ids = [];
    this.id_Reg;
    this.active = false;
    this.$container = $('#' + elmId);
}
List.prototype = {
    'loadShow': function() {},
    'createShow': function(containers) {
        var list = this, 
            showid, newid, show, $row, $cln;
        if (list.active) {
            showid = list.ids.indexOf(list.id_reg);
            list.active = false;
        } else {
            newid = (list.shows.length > 0) ? list.shows[list.shows.length - 1].obj.id + 1 : 0;
            show = new Show(newid, containers.$inputFields);
            $row = show.makeRow().appendTo(containers.$table);

            // attaching anonymous event handlers here allows access to various outer vars through closure; eg containers, list, show, $row, $cln
            $row.find('button.edit_show').on('click', function(e) {
                show.active = true;
                list.active = true;
                list.id_reg = newid;
                containers.$stdContainer.hide();
                containers.$editContainer.show();
                show.edit(containers.$inputFields);
            });
            $row.find('button.delete_show').on('click', function(e) {
                $row.remove();
                $cln.remove();
                var index = list.ids.indexOf(newid);
                list.shows.splice(index, 1);
                list.ids.splice(index, 1);
            });
            $row.find('input.activate_show').on('change', function activate(e) {
                // ...
            });
            $cln = $row.clone(true, true).appendTo(list.$container); // with (true, true), then clone inherits $row's event handlers.
            list.shows.push(show);
            list.ids.push(newid);
        }
        containers.$stdContainer.show();
        containers.$editContainer.hide();
    }
}

var list = new List('finalplaylist');

$(function() {
    $('.store_show').each(function(i, elm) {
        $(elm).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // do all the high level DOM traversal here
            var $p = $(this).parent();
            list.createShow({
                '$inputFields': $p.find('input'),
                '$table': $p.parent().find('table'),
                '$stdContainer': $p.parent().children().eq(0),
                '$editContainer': $p.parent().children().eq(1)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You should recognize much of your original code but it's been shuffled around - refactored.

Refactoring is commonplace. Even very experienced programmers find they need to refactor, and it's is an important part of their skill-set. It's seldom necessary to restart from scratch.